# How can I put an a tag in the middle of a box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

The following is my code to create three boxes with link text inside it.

HTML:

```
<div class="amount-box">
    <div class="25">
      <a href="">$25</a>
    </div>
    <div class="50">
      <a href="">$50</a>
    </div>
    <div class="100">
      <a href="">$100</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- amount box -->
```

CSS:

```
.amount-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box > div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/opztnkx9/1/

Is there a better way for me to put the links in the middle of the box with having to use margin-top?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are already using a `flexbox`, you can make each of `.amount_box > div` also a `flexbox` and give it `align-items: center` to align it vertically - see demo below:

[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcyryv5a/)

```css
.amount-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">

  <div class="25">
    <a href="">$25</a>
  </div>
  <div class="50">
    <a href="">$50</a>
  </div>
  <div class="100">
    <a href="">$100</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- amount box -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply the same `flexbox` technique to the children as well. Add following css:

```
.amount-box > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.amount-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box > div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">
  <div class="25">
    <a href="">$25</a>
  </div>
  <div class="50">
    <a href="">$50</a>
  </div>
  <div class="100">
    <a href="">$100</a>
  </div>
</div><!-- amount box -->
```

Comment: Oops!I never thought of trying that. Thanks it works

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple approach if it just for one line such as this.

```
.amount-box  {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```css
.amount-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box  {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.amount-box > div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">
    
    <div class="25">
      <a href="">$25</a>
    </div>
    <div class="50">
      <a href="">$50</a>
    </div>
    <div class="100">
      <a href="">$100</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- amount box -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `line-height`

```css
.amount-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box > div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
 .amount-box a{
  line-height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">

<div class="25">
  <a href="">$25</a>
</div>
<div class="50">
  <a href="">$50</a>
</div>
<div class="100">
  <a href="">$100</a>
</div>
  </div><!-- amount box -->
```

Also try absolute positioning  - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/opztnkx9/3/

```css
.amount-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.amount-box > div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
position: relative;
}
.amount-box a{
 position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">

<div class="25">
  <a href="">$25</a>
</div>
<div class="50">
  <a href="">$50</a>
</div>
<div class="100">
  <a href="">$100</a>
</div>
  </div><!-- amount box -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The `display: flex` answers certainly are great but doesn't have quite as good browser support as the alternatives (IE has some bugs and no support in IE <= 9).

If the text is limited to one line you can simply use `line-height` to center the text vertically. If line height = content height then text will be centered. This should work even on quite old browsers.

```
.amount-box > div{
  line-height:50px;
}
```

If you need multiple lines then you can use `display: table;` as demonstrated on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

From that page:

HTML:

```
<div class="something-semantic">
    <div class="something-else-semantic">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.something-semantic {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.something-else-semantic {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the Flexbox approach also for the inner DIV. Simply paste

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

to your `.amount-box > div`selector.

Answer (score 0):

Display flex is the best solution for your answer.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/elicohenator/pen/rWLKWr

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Abs aligned :)</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make links `display:inline-block` to use `margin-top`

```
.amount-box a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is snippet -** Try this

```css
.amount-box{
  display: flex;
 
  
}
.amount-box > div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="amount-box">
    
    <div class="25">
      <a href="">$25</a>
    </div>
    <div class="50">
      <a href="">$50</a>
    </div>
    <div class="100">
      <a href="">$100</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- amount box -->
```